# Variable might not have been initiialized but should be because of an if else if

Tags: java, variables

```
compteur = compteur + 1;
if ( compteur == 1 ) {
    petiteComm = commTotal;
    grandeComm = commTotal;
} else {
    if ( commTotal < petiteComm ) {
        petiteComm = commTotal; 
    }
    if ( commTotal > grandeComm ) {
         grandeComm = commTotal;
    }
}
```

it says petiteComm might not have been initiliazed but it will be because of the first if since the compteur will be at 1 the first time. I dont know what to do to fix that.

Comment: Give it a valid initial value. What's the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write a petiteComm = 0 before the if.
That should help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what language you're working with here, but it sounds like you're overestimating the compiler, regardless.

As others have mentioned, you need to give it an initial value. You can do that however you see so fit, but looking at the syntax you've given us,

```
petiteComm = 0;
```

should work. I'd probably be tempted to set it to `null` or `-1`, but without knowing more about the circumstances, I wouldn't want to assume anything more about it.

In general, compilers don't look for second-tier consequences. That is, they'll tell you if a variable is never given a value, as you're seeing here, but they aren't "smart" enough to infer whether they'll be given a value.

Consider the following code block, which illustrates the same error as you're seeing, but a bit more succinctly:

```
x = 0

if(x == 0) {
    y = 10;
}

print(y);
```

`x` will *always* be zero, so that `if` block will always execute, but (most, including yours) compilers won't be able to detect that. They'll just see an uninitialized `y` variable being used out of nowhere. The simple solution is to initialize `y` with a default value. Alternatively, you could throw an exception in the `else` block to indicate that something unexpected has happened, or operations were run out of order. That exception should, again depending on the language, count as an exit route and consequently evade any more checks like you're seeing.

It's all just a matter of circumstances.